# CriteriaBuilder and using alias for select cause

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql, criteria-api

I would like to create a query with CriteriaBuilder for this kind of sql;

```
SELECT myDefinedAlias.id, myDefinedAlias.name, myDefinedAlias.aFieldForFK select from Person as myDefinedAlias where myDefinedAlias.name = ?1
```

**How can i accomplish defining an alias for this?**

I can create queries without aliases but i cannot define aliases...

```
CriteriaQuery<Person> cq = criteriBuilder.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> person = cq.from(Person.class);
cq = cq.select(person);
cq = cq.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(person.get(Person_.name), "Chivas")))
```

I need this for QueryHints, batch fetch.

```
.setHint(QueryHints.BATCH, "myDefinedAlias.aFieldForFK.itsNestedAttribute");
```

I am stuck and couldn't find anything regarding my problem. Anyone?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. JPA needs the sql-statement-aliases for itself to use when generating sql-statements.
For the nested query hints to work, the relationship needs to be specified in the entities.
For example, if your Person entity have a OneToMany mapping to a House entity - and the property name in the Person class is livedInHouses. The query hint would become:
.setHint(QueryHints.BATCH, "Person.livedInHouses"). Its damn near impossible to use FKs that exists in the database but are not annotated as relations on/in entities in JPA.

Comment: Sorry for late response... Yes you were right. i checked if i could fetch by "Person" annotation and it was correct. I had to change my way of building queries. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Doing `cq.select(person).alias("myDefinedAlias")` assigns your alias which can subsequently be used in batch/fetch query hints. Eclipselink supports nested fetch joins as long as you do not transfer to-Many relations (collections). 
I.e.`.setHint(QueryHints.BATCH,  myDefinedAlias.toOneRelation.toManyRelation")` works while `.setHint(QueryHints.BATCH, .setHint(QueryHints.BATCH, "myDefinedAlias.toManyRelation.toOneRelation")` shouldn't.